# Regex for code editor - Numeric range including decimal

Tags: regex, code-editor

I am looking for a regular expression to match a numeric range within a code editor. In my example it is Brackets by Adobe or Textmate.

Match numeric range between 60 up to 300 including numbers like 60.34323

You can see here what I mean...

https://regex101.com/r/aPlUs0/1

It is working well but does not work within the code editor.

```
^(?:[6-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2,2})(?:\.\d+)?$|^300$
```

Does anybody know, how to change the expression that it is also working within code eitors?

Comment: I don' know Brackets or Textmate but it does work with Sublime Text.

Comment: Yes, indeed - see my new answer below for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: sir, code editors also have a check box for regular expressions, in their find/search box. but do you mean that, you need to match the numeric values, with mentioned criteria, within some other code? for example, do you need to match the number 60.1 in this line of code: float a = 60.1; because in that case your RegEx needs a little more adjustment. just clarify your case, so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I realized that it is also working in Brackets. The problem is formatted code (indented). But I have a huge code and it is indented. So, how does the expression also find indented code?

[image: Example Brackets]

Comment: Try  asserting not a non whitespace char before and after `(?<!\S)(?:(?:[6-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2,2})(?:\.\d+)?|300)(?!\S)`

Comment: My solution now is to unindent the code by using SHIFT+TAB. When everything is unindented, the regex-code does work. Thank you all for your contribution :-).

Comment: This should be an edit to your question. It shouldn't be posted as an answer.